# Unity - When exactly are objects in the hierarchy instatiated?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Let's imagine I have a prefabbed object.

I can either add it to the hierarchy by hand or instantiate it dynamically in some 'awake' method, for example.

My question is, is the first method anyhow faster?
Does Unity perform any optimizations based on what is on the hierarchy before the game runs?

Or it just the same and internally Unity simply calls the Instantiate method on all the objects on the hierarchy before the game starts?

BTW: Does any of you know a book that teaches Unity in-depth?

Comment: I am not from Unity and don't know exactly how they made it but if you think about it all objects have to be loaded into memory anyway. The difference should not be dramatic or noticeable by your users. You can do some test with profiler to see if there is a big difference.

Comment: Thank you Dave, yes you are probably right although I want to be sure because I am developing a game on mobiles and potential 'lags' are not what I want :)

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: No problem. That is why you instantiate your objects on `Awake` or `Start`. If the objects were instantiated from Hierarchy or your code doesn't matter for game performance. What has greater impact on performance is calling `Destroy` on your objects and unnecessary instantiation during runtime. You should definitely use object pooling if you want to create and destroy many objects on runtime.

Comment: And when it comes to a book for learning Unity I strongly recommend their official documentation and tutorials.

Comment: `Awake()`, by definition, happens after the scene is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're possibly over-optimizing here. You're worrying too much about something that likely won't have any measurable impact on your game.

I would suggest approaching it from a usability standpoint. If your object is permanent in the scene, or should start in the scene, why not put it into your hierarchy before running? This lets you view it, move it around, and see how it interacts with other objects.

On the other hand if you object should be dynamically created on the fly, then it probably shouldn't be in the scene from the get go, and perhaps should only be created when needed.

I would approach these kind of problems with your use-case in mind, rather than worrying about optimizing too much during development. Only when you run into slow downs etc, then use profilers and testing to see where you can cut some corners.

One important thing to remember is that a highly-optimized unfinished game is not playable, whereas a less-optimized but finished game is. Spend more time on your game mechanics and getting it done, then if needed, optimize it.